# output a variable in a text file

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

I have some Java code like here:

```
public synchronized void printLinkStatistics(Logger log)
{
    log.info("\tInput Port = " + inputPort);
    Set <Long> ts = statData.keySet();
    for(Long t: ts)
    {   double utilization = statData.get(t);
        if (utilization!=0.0) 
        {
            utilization *= 8.0;
            utilization /= 1e6;
            if (!Double.isNaN(utilization))
            {
            log.info("\t\tTimestamp = " + t + ", Utilization = " + utilization + "Mbps");

           }
        }
    }
}
```

and this code will write utilization in console but I need also write utilization + timestamp in a file to draw the pilot in future.
How I create file with this variable?
I'm using Eclipse in Ubuntu 12.04

**EDITH** 
I'm doing this but the file is empty:

```
public synchronized void printLinkStatistics(Logger log)
{ 
    try
    {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    log.info("\tInput Port = " + inputPort);
    Set <Long> ts = statData.keySet();
    for(Long t: ts)
    {   double utilization = statData.get(t);
        if (utilization!=0.0) 
        {
            utilization *= 8.0;
            utilization /= 1e6;
            if (!Double.isNaN(utilization))
            {
            log.info("\t\tTimestamp = " + t + ", Utilization = " + utilization + "Mbps");
            pw.println("\t\tTimestamp = " + t + ", Utilization = " + utilization + "Mbps");
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //handle exception as you want
                                        }
}
```

Comment: Use `FileWriter`, it's a pretty simple implementation. Google is your friend for this one.

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII Well you right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and redirect output to file . PrintWriter has many useful methods which makes writing ouput easier(read java docs for more info). E.g.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
pw.println("hello");
pw.flush();
```

Your updated code will look like this

```
public synchronized void printLinkStatistics(Logger log, PrintWriter writer)
{
    log.info("\tInput Port = " + inputPort);
    Set <Long> ts = statData.keySet();
    for(Long t: ts)
    {   double utilization = statData.get(t);
        if (utilization!=0.0) 
        {
            utilization *= 8.0;
            utilization /= 1e6;
            if (!Double.isNaN(utilization))
            {
            log.info("\t\tTimestamp = " + t + ", Utilization = " + utilization + "Mbps");
      writer.println("\t\tTimestamp = " + t + ", Utilization = " + utilization + "Mbps");

           }
        }
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```

In order to invoke your method you need to wrap you code in [try/catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block like this

```
try {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    printLinkStatistics(logger, pw);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); //handle exception as you want
}
```

Comment: hi. thnx  for answer but as you can see i need to add to this file in each For loop iteration how i can do it?

Comment: do i need just pw.println("hello"); to add?

Comment: where is output.txt file?

Comment: @arashams i updated the answer with changed that you need to make in your method

Comment: thnx for your great answer .where i must create the output.txt file? Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: It will be created automatically

Comment: this line has error: PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));  Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: @arashams you need to handle the checked exception, see the answer

Comment: Ive made change to my post, plz help me

Comment: @arashams you are missing pw.flush(), see my answer carefully(there is a line writer.flush())

Comment: Do this PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true));